# Warning: array_intersect() [function.array-intersect]: Argument #1 is not an array in

Tags: php, mysql

If my first argument only has one return I get that warning:  I'm trying to find a match in the second array and then do something.  So I want to match the variable, in the first return to the array in the second argument.

```
$this->view->user = $this->user;

//  START  //
$user_id = $this->view->user->user_id;

$region_id = $this->db->fetchAll("SELECT region_id FROM regions WHERE manager_id='$user_id' ORDER BY region_id ASC");   
$ris = $region_id[0]['region_id'];
$rs = trim($ris, '');

echo '<pre><strong>ASSIGNED REGIONS:</strong><br />';
    var_dump($rs);
echo '<br /><br /></pre>';



    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile("/js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js");

    $this->view->sidebar = $this->view->render("sidebars/alerts.phtml");

    //get news
    $alerts = $this->user->getAlerts($_GET['sort'], $_GET['search']);
    $collection = array();

    foreach($alerts AS $item){
            $ars = $item["assigned_regionals"];
                echo '<pre>ASSIGNED REGIONALS:<br />';
                    var_dump($ars);
                echo '</pre>';  



        echo '<strong>ASSIGNED REGION:</strong><br />'.$ars.'<br />';
            $ar = trim($ars, '|');
            $a = explode('|', $ar);
            var_dump($a);


            $i = array_intersect($rs, $a);
            if (!empty($i)) {
                $collection[] = new Stax_Alert($item);

                echo '<br /><br /><pre><strong>ALERT REGIONS:</strong><br />';
                    var_dump($a);
                echo '</pre>';
            }

    }
```

Comment: Probably `$rs` is string. So, it is trully not an array.

Comment: If the trim doesn't throw an error to $rs in line 6 then it is a string.

Comment: Was it so hard to var_dump($rs); before array_intersect call, and see it's value?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough: your first parameter ($rs)( is a string. That's certainly what the code is doing.

You probably want something like this:

```
        if (in_array($rs, $a)) {
            $collection[] = new Stax_Alert($item);

            echo '<br /><br /><pre><strong>ALERT REGIONS:</strong><br />';
                var_dump($a);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
```